# Validate construction of typescript model

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a person model for example

```
export class Person {

    name: string;
    id: Number;
}
```

I want to make sure that name and id are the only fields to be defined

So when I construct the Object like the following(METHOD 1)

```
let person = new Person({name: 'john', id:2, invalidField: 'notAllowed'})
```

Typescript does not allow this above

However if I get the data from the backend it will allow it to construct the object like the following(METHOD 2)

```
  let data: any = {name: 'john', id:2, invalidField: 'notAllowed'}// resp from backend
  let person = new Person(data)
```

Typescript allows this above

Is there anyway to make sure that constructing the object via method two gets invalidated?

The reason I want to able to do this is so I can create unit tests to make sure that data from the backend is in the format that I expect

Not sure if this is clear I'm fairly new to typescript
Any questions please add a comments

Maybe some run-time check in the constructor?

Comment: This test doesn't make any sense to me. The front end doesn't control what's returned (unless you're using GraphQL or something)--the front end cannot test all permutations of what an API it doesn't control returns. TypeScript is (roughly) compile-time type checking, although IIRC there are run-time options. Threads like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573 may help explain in more detail.

Comment: @DaveNewton the idea of the test is that it will catch changes to the model. So if someone on the backend team changes person.name to person.firstName my test will catch this. I will be passing my own data to my tests. So basically the backend changes name to firstName then someone on the frontend changes to person model to person.firstName and that may or may not be the correct thing to do

Comment: Well your "backend" `data` has type `any`, of course that won't be typechecked. But it sounds like you are asking for a runtime typecheck, which TypeScript doesn't do anyway?

Comment: @Bergi yes a runtime check, is this possible?

Comment: So this is an integration test, not a unit test. You can look in to run-time type checking extensions (I know nothing about them), otherwise you'll just need to validate JS as usual, which it'd seem like you'd need some of anyway.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript. Such verifications will not work at runtime.
You need to implement that manually. I believe you are looking for something like [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/).